# how to stop the audio which plays in background

Tags: jquery, content-management-system

In cms(wordpress), I uploaded a video. once i clicked the video, it plays well. once i closed it, video gets closed but audio continues to play even after i close it. please help me to close the audio also.

```js
<script>
    jQuery(document).on("click", ".nivo-lightbox-overlay", function (e) {
        var $video = jQuery('video', jQuery(this));
        $video[0].pause();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

function enableMute() { 
    vid.muted = true;
} 

function disableMute() { 
    vid.muted = false;
} 

function checkMute() { 
    alert(vid.muted);
}
```

Check this Example

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_muted.asp